# Getting an error trying to use native select with angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to use the native select as it is more accessible, instead of mat-select. I've followed the [documented example](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) verbatim to try to get started:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <select matNativeControl required>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
     </select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

However I'm getting this, `ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.`

In my module I have:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatButtonModule, MatTabsModule, MatSelectModule, MatCardModule, MatSlideToggleModule, MatFormFieldModule,
     MatInputModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatTableModule, MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material';*/
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatTooltipModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        MyComponent
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class MyModule { }
```

I've searched for this error and the general solution is to add a missing module, but I don't see what I'm missing here. `mat-select` doesn't cause an error. I'm beginning to wonder if the documentation is wrong or out-of-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use material `select` or `input` in  `mat-form-field`.
If you wanna use native select you can't use  `mat-form-field` use simple `div` with some styles like in `mat-form-field`.

**EDIT** Sorry this solution work use `matNativeControl` in `select`

But try to update material to the lastest version:

```
ng update @angular/material
```

Comment: So is this a mistake in the official documentation?

Comment: No. I it is my mistake it allow. Now i try why it dont work on your code.Sorry for miss solution

Comment: I dont see exactle why it dont work. Try to check your code with this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ueye29?file=material-module.ts

Comment: try to update material to last version, What version you have?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't update material on this project at this time (I can make an argument for it though), so I can't test this answer right now.